# Ansibly copy with_items only if variable is true

Tags: bash, ansible, jinja2

I have this:

```
- name: copy services
  copy: src={{ item }} dest="{{ dir.consul }}/services" mode=0755 owner=devops group=devops
  with_items:
    - services/FG.json
    - services/IC.json
    - services/java.json
    - services/NODE.json
    - services/repo.json
```

I also have a boolean variable set for each of the services to indicate if I want them or not.
Problems:

1. The variables are from bash - this makes the options true\false where I think ansible reads True\False, should I convert them before-hand?
2. Can I copy only items that their var is true??
   For example when `{{ fg }}` is true, copy `fg`

Comment: add `when` statement – it is evaluated for every item in your loop.

Comment: But I need a different `when` for every item. @KonstantinSuvorov

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
- name: copy services
  copy: src="/services/{{ item }}.json" dest="{{ dir.consul }}/services" mode=0755 owner=devops group=devops
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname][item|lower] == True
  with_items:
    - FG
    - IC
    - java
    - NODE
    - repo
```

Update: fully autonomous example

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    fg: True
    ic: False
    java: True
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      when: vars[item|lower] == True
      with_items:
        - FG
        - IC
        - java
```

If variables to check are host facts, use `hostvars` object;
If variables are play vars, `vars` object can be used.
You don't specify in your question how you pass variables into your playbook.

I use `item|lower` because my vars are low cased while items haver mixed case.

Comment: What is `hostvars` for? I tried it with your example and got `fatal: [10.2.1.108] => error while evaluating conditional: hostvars[inventory_hostname][item|lower] == True`, and with `{{ item|lower }}` and got `when: "{{ item|lower }}" == True
                           ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.`

Comment: Konstantin has given an example, do not use it. Use `when` statement to achieve what you want or add more information to your post.

Comment: Updated my answer with complete example. Don't understand why it can't be used – it illustrates `when` statement with dynamic variables names based on items values.

Comment: the variables are passed through jenkins to a var file of ansible that looks like this: `---
IC: "{{ lookup('env','IC') }}"`